# ptracing long-running process hangs

Tags: go, ptrace

I'm using Go's syscall package Ptrace interface to trace a process. The problem is, if the tracee is long-running, the tracing seems to hang. I tried replicating the issue with C implementation, but there everything seems to work fine.

Here's a Go code to reproduce the issue:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    len := "9999999"
    cmd := exec.Command("openssl", "rand", "-hex", len)
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Ptrace: true}
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Start()
    pid, _ := syscall.Wait4(-1, nil, syscall.WALL, nil)

    for {
        syscall.PtraceSyscall(pid, 0)
        _, err := syscall.Wait4(-1, nil, syscall.WALL, nil) 

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

When running the above code, the process never completes and it has to be interrupted. If the `len` variable is changed to something smaller, for example `9`, the process will complete without issues and output will be something following:

```
$ go run main.go
d2ff963e65e8e1926b
no child processes
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Go? Where is the process blocked?

Comment: i'm using the latest version. in the above code, the process is blocked at `syscall.Wait4` inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Found it. The program hangs when Go runtime changes the thread in which the goroutine is running. Can be verified in the example code by printing `fmt.Println(syscall.Gettid())` inside the loop:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    len := "9999999"
    cmd := exec.Command("openssl", "rand", "-hex", len)
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Ptrace: true}
    cmd.Start()

    pid, _ := syscall.Wait4(-1, nil, syscall.WALL, nil)

    for {
        fmt.Println(syscall.Gettid())
        syscall.PtraceSyscall(pid, 0)
        _, err := syscall.Wait4(-1, nil, syscall.WALL, nil)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Solution: lock the execution of the goroutine to its current thread by using `runtime.LockOSThread()`:

```
....
func main() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()
    len := "9999999"
    cmd := exec.Command("openssl", "rand", "-hex", len)
....
```